# Sheafification: another definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let be $\mathcal F$ a presheaf on a topological space $X$,
the usual definition of the sheaf associated to $\mathcal F$ is the following

$\mathcal F^+(U)=\{\widetilde s: U\rightarrow Et(\mathcal F)\;|\; s\in \mathcal F(U),\;\textrm{and}\;\widetilde s(x)=s_x \}$

where $s_x$ is the germ at $x$ of $s$.

In the book "Algebraic geometry: an introduction - D.Perrin," I have found another definition of the sheaf associated to a presheaf in the particular case of sheaves of functions.

Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf (on $X$) of functions with codomain the set $A$. Then

$\mathcal F^+(U)=\{f:U\rightarrow A\;|\;\forall x\in U, \exists V\subseteq U\;
\textrm{where $V$ is an open set containing $x$ and}\; \exists g\in\mathcal F(V)\;\textrm{such that}\; f|_V=g\}$

My question is the following: why, in the case of sheaves of functions, these definitions are the same? The nature of the elements of $\mathcal F^+(U)$ is different, in fact in the first case we have a function from $U$ to $Et(\mathcal F)$ whereas in the second case the codomain is $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal F$ is a presheaf of sets on a topological space $X$, the etale space construction shows that you can interpret $\mathcal F$ as a presheaf of continuous functions into the topological splace $Et(\mathcal F)$ :

If $s \in \mathcal F(U)$, you associate it to the function $\widetilde{s} : x \in U\mapsto s_x \in Et(\mathcal F)$. Write $\widetilde {\mathcal F}(U) = \{\widetilde{s}, s \in \mathcal F(U)\}$. Together with the obvious restriction maps, it is a presheaf on $X$ isomorphic to $\mathcal F$

Now that we have as a presheaf of functions into $Et(\mathcal F)$, we can use Perrin's definition : $\widetilde {\mathcal F}^+(U)$ is the set of functions $U \to Et(\mathcal F)$ that are locally elements of $\widetilde {\mathcal F}(U)$ :

$\widetilde {\mathcal F}^+(U) = \{f : U \to Et(\mathcal F) / \forall x \in U, \exists g \in \widetilde {\mathcal F} (V), g = f|_V \}$ , where $V$ is an open containing $x$.
$ = \{ f : U \to Et(\mathcal F) / \forall x \in U, \exists g \in \widetilde {\mathcal F} (V), f_x = g_x \} \\
 = \{ f : U \to Et(\mathcal F) / \forall x \in U, \exists s \in \mathcal F (V), f_x = \widetilde{s}_x \} \\
 = \{ f : U \to Et(\mathcal F) / \forall x \in U, \exists s \in \mathcal F (V), f(x) = s_x \}$
because the germ of a function into the etale space is determined by its image at that point, and $\widetilde{s}(x) = s_x$.

Thus the two definitions end up with the same sheaf in the end.

Comment: I think your second paragraph may be wrong. Denote $\pi:\operatorname{Et}(\mathcal{F})\to X$ to the canonical projection, and denote $\operatorname{Sect}\pi$ to the sheaf over $X$ of sections of $\pi$. Denote $\iota:\mathcal{F}\to\operatorname{Sect}\pi$ to the presheaf map $\iota_U:s\in\mathcal{F}(U)\mapsto (x\in U\mapsto s_x\in\operatorname{Et}(\mathcal{F}))$. Then $\iota$ is the sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$, which is known to be injective (i.e., all $\iota_U$ are injective) if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is a separated presheaf. So in general the maps $\iota_U$ are not bijections and

Comment: therefore $\mathcal{F}$ won't be isomorphic to $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}$. Another way of seeing this: every subpresheaf of a separated presheaf is a separated presheaf. Since $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}^+=\operatorname{Sect}\pi$ is always a sheaf, in particular is a separated presheaf and therefore the subsheaf $\widetilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is separated. But the presheaf $\mathcal{F}$, which is arbitrary, may not be separated.